# The ridge estimator from $[({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})'X'X({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})]$ subject to $\beta'\beta≤d$

Tags: optimization, regression, linear-regression

I have this question:
Show that the ridge estimator of $β$, denoted $\hat{\beta}_{Ridge}$ can be obtained as the solution to the constraint optimization problem:
Minimize w.r.t. ${\beta}$
$[({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})'X'X({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})]$ subject to $\beta'\beta≤d$
Where $\beta_{LS}$ is the ordinary least-squares estimator of $\beta$ and $d>0$ is an ordinary constant. I noted the existence of this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205/how-to-derive-the-ridge-regression-solution, however it don't really formulate the problem in the same way.

Ok, so what I got is this:
$({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS})'X'X({\beta}-\hat{\beta}_{LS}) + \lambda \beta' \beta=\beta' X'X \beta - \beta' X'X \hat{\beta}_{LS} - \hat{\beta}_{LS}' X'X \beta + \hat{\beta}_{LS}' X'X \hat{\beta}_{LS} + \beta'  \lambda I \beta = \beta' X'X \beta - 2\beta' X'X \hat{\beta}_{LS} + \hat{\beta}_{LS}' X'X \hat{\beta}_{LS} +  \beta' \lambda I \beta $
Since $\hat{\beta}_{LS} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$ we get:
$\beta' X'X \beta -2\beta'X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'y + y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'y + \beta' \lambda I \beta = \beta'X'X\beta -2\beta'X'y + y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'y + \beta' \lambda I \beta$
But here is where I get stuck. I want $y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ to be equal to $y'y$ but I don't know how.
Please MathStack help me. You are my only hope.

P.S. $\lambda$ is a scalar.

Comment: The matrix $X(X^\intercal X)^{-1} X^\intercal$ is usually called the _projection_ matrix (as it project orthogonally onto the subspace $\mathsf{Im}(X)$) and is denoted by $P.$ Then, it is idempotent and so $y^\intercal P y = \| Py \|^2;$ by orthogonality, $\|y\|^2 = \|Py\|^2 + \|e\|^2,$ where $e = (I - P)y = y - Py$ is the residual vector. So, unless you had a perfect fit, $\|Py\|^2 < \|y\|^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the hat matrix $H$, thus
$$
Hy=\hat{y},
$$
hence, 
$$
y'Hy = y'\hat{y}=y'(y+e)=y'y+y'e=y'y.
$$
The last equality stems from the first order condition of 
$$
\nabla_{\beta}S(\beta)=0.
$$

Comment: Once again Vancak you come to my rescue. Thank you!